# RegExp for Blank, Tabs or blank spaces in textbox

Tags: javascript, regex

I need the help of the experts on this forum.

I would like to come up with a RegEx (javascript) to validate a textbox which has any blank spaces in it, any blank tabs in it, and also check for an empty textbox?

ie.

```
alert("Accepted")
------------------------------
Jameswithsometext
Billy Jean

alert("Not accepted")
------------------------------
- inadvertenly typed blank spaces
- inadvertenly typed tabs
- blank textbox
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\s` should match any whitespace character. So if that's all there is, you have a problem.

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('mytextbox');
if (/^\s*$/.test(textbox.value)) {
  alert('Come on man, seriously, what the hell are you doing?');
} else {
  alert('Accepted');
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/68KzX/

- `^` start of string
- `\s` any whitespace character
- `*` match any number of characters
- `$` end of string

So this will match if the string has zero characters, or if it has *only* whitespace characters.

Comment: Aabsolutely genious. I truely wish I knew regex. Its so powerful! Thank you so very much.

Comment: @user1451890 I just explained the regexp parts a bit more, see my edit.

Comment: It is much more efficient to use `if (!/\S/.test(…))` instead because search can stop if any non-whitespace is found.

Answer (score 1):

Using `/^\S+$/` (at least one character of non-whitespace) we can do,

```
var p = prompt("Enter text", "");
var rx = /^\S+$/;
if (rx.test(p) == false)
    alert("Not accepted");
else
    alert("Accepted");
```

Note that this also handles the case of nothing entered.

Comment: Comparing a boolean return value with `==` against `false` is superfluous. Comparing with `==` (type-converting) against `false` is error-prone to begin with. You are looking for `if (!rx.test(p))` and might as well use `if (rx.test(p))` and reverse the order of the branches (which should be in blocks).